# Can I change the max bank angle on the Garmin G1000 in the C172SP?

Tags: avionics, autopilot, cessna-172, g1000

I wonder if I can change the max bank angle on the G1000/GFC700 avionics in a C172SP, like you can on the MCP of the 737NG?